# How to correctly generate list of UTC timestamps, by hour, between two datetimes Python?

Tags: python, datetime, datediff, python-datetime

I'm new to Python. After a couple days researching and trying things out, I've landed on a decent solution for creating a list of timestamps, for each hour, between two dates.

**Example:**

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

timestamp_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'

earliest_ts_str = '2020-10-01T15:00:00Z'
earliest_ts_obj = datetime.strptime(earliest_ts_str, timestamp_format)

latest_ts_str = '2020-10-02T00:00:00Z'
latest_ts_obj = datetime.strptime(latest_ts_str, timestamp_format)

num_days = latest_ts_obj - earliest_ts_obj
num_hours = int(round(num_days.total_seconds() / 3600,0))

ts_raw = []
for ts in range(num_hours):
    ts_raw.append(latest_ts_obj - timedelta(hours = ts + 1))

dates_formatted = [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') for d in ts_raw]

# Need timestamps in ascending order
dates_formatted.reverse()

dates_formatted
```

**Which results in:**

```
['2020-10-01T00:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T01:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T02:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T03:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T04:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T05:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T06:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T07:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T08:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T09:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T10:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T11:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T12:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T13:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T14:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T15:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T16:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T17:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T18:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T19:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T20:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T21:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T22:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T23:00:00Z']
```

**Problem:**

- If I change `earliest_ts_str` to include **minutes**, say `earliest_ts_str = '2020-10-01T19:45:00Z'`, the resulting list does **not** increment the minute intervals accordingly.

**Results:**

```
['2020-10-01T20:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T21:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T22:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T23:00:00Z']
```

**I need it to be:**

```
['2020-10-01T20:45:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T21:45:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T22:45:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T23:45:00Z']
```

Feels like the problem is in the `num_days` and `num_hours` calculation, but I can't see how to fix it.

Ideas?

Comment: Fix your code. There are 3 NameErrors in the code - `str_format`  and `dates_raw` are not defined. You define different names before that. and last line does not print `dates_formated`

Comment: Oops. Pardon me. Had this post open as I was discovering things. It evolved. Now cleaned up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

timestamp_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'

earliest_ts_str = '2020-10-01T00:00:00Z'
ts_obj = datetime.strptime(earliest_ts_str, timestamp_format)

latest_ts_str = '2020-10-02T00:00:00Z'
latest_ts_obj = datetime.strptime(latest_ts_str, timestamp_format)

ts_raw = []
while ts_obj <= latest_ts_obj:
    ts_raw.append(ts_obj)
    ts_obj += timedelta(hours=1)

dates_formatted = [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') for d in ts_raw]
print(dates_formatted)
```

EDIT:

Here is example with [Maya](https://pypi.org/project/maya/)

```
import maya

earliest_ts_str = '2020-10-01T00:00:00Z'
latest_ts_str = '2020-10-02T00:00:00Z'
start = maya.MayaDT.from_iso8601(earliest_ts_str)
end = maya.MayaDT.from_iso8601(latest_ts_str)

# end is not included, so we add 1 second
my_range = maya.intervals(start=start, end=end.add(seconds=1), interval=60*60)
dates_formatted = [d.iso8601() for d in my_range]
print(dates_formatted)
```

Both output

```
['2020-10-01T00:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-01T01:00:00Z',
 ... some left out ...
 '2020-10-01T23:00:00Z',
 '2020-10-02T00:00:00Z']
```

Comment: Thats brilliant @buran. I'm going to study this. It simplified quite a lot. Thank you.

Comment: there is lot for improvement/refactoring. I kept it as close as possible to yours code. If you don't mind using third party package like Maya, there is convenient function to generate intervals.

Answer (score 3):

if you don't mind to use a 3rd party package, have a look at [pandas.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```
import pandas as pd

earliest, latest = '2020-10-01T15:45:00Z', '2020-10-02T00:00:00Z'

dti = pd.date_range(earliest, latest, freq='H') # just specify hourly frequency...
l = dti.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').to_list()
print(l)
# ['2020-10-01T15:45:00Z', '2020-10-01T16:45:00Z', '2020-10-01T17:45:00Z', '2020-10-01T18:45:00Z', '2020-10-01T19:45:00Z', '2020-10-01T20:45:00Z', '2020-10-01T21:45:00Z', '2020-10-01T22:45:00Z', '2020-10-01T23:45:00Z']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
num_hours = num_days.days*24 + num_days.seconds//3600
```

The problem is that `num_days` only takes integer values, so if it is not a multiple of 24h you will get the floor value (i.e for your example you will get 0). So in order to compute the hours you need to use both, days and seconds.

Also, you can create the list directly in the right order, I am not sure if you are doing it like this for some reason.

```
ts_raw.append(earliest_ts_obj + timedelta(hours = ts + 1))
```